React Issue - Multiple items will be add in Cart
"I'm having an issue where, when I add an item to the cart, it seems to be adding all items at once, instead of just the one I clicked on."

FoodItem.jsx File ->
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import './FoodItem.css'
import { assets } from '../../assets/assets'
import { StoreContext } from '../../context/StoreContext'


const FoodItem = ({id, name, price, description, image}) => {


    const {cartItems,addToCart,removeFromCart} = useContext(StoreContext);

    return (
    <div className='food-item'>
        <div className="food-item-img-container">
            <img className='food-item-image' src={image} alt=''></img>
            {
                !cartItems[id]
                ?<img className="add" onClick={() => addToCart(id)} src={assets.add_icon_white} alt=''></img>
                :<div className='food-item-counter'>
                    <img onClick={()=>removeFromCart(id)} src={assets.remove_icon_red} alt="" />
                    <p>{cartItems[id]}</p>
                    <img onClick={()=>addToCart(id)} src={assets.add_icon_green} alt=''></img>

                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div className="food-item-info">
            <div className="food-item-name-rating">
                <p>{name}</p>
                <img src={assets.rating_starts} alt=''></img>
            </div>
            <p className="food-item-desc">
                {description}
            </p>
            <p className="food-item-price">
                 &#8377;{price}
            </p>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default FoodItem

StoreContext.jsx File ->
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { food_list } from "../assets/assets";

export const StoreContext = createContext({});

const StoreContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState({});

    const addToCart = (itemId) => {
        if(!cartItems[itemId]){
            setCartItems((prev)=>({...prev,[itemId]:1}))
        }
        else{
            setCartItems((prev)=>({...prev,[itemId]:prev[itemId]+1}))
        }
    }

const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
      
            setCartItems((prev)=>({...prev,[itemId]:prev[itemId]-1}))
        }
            
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log(cartItems)
        },[cartItems])

    const contextValue = {

        food_list, 
        cartItems,
        setCartItems,
        addToCart,
        removeFromCart

    }

    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {props.children}
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )

}


export default StoreContextProvider;


I tried checking the addToCart function to ensure that it's only updating the state for the specific item I clicked on. I also reviewed the component to make sure it's correctly receiving and displaying the cartItems state. Additionally, I added a console.log to see if the itemId passed to the function matches the item being clicked.

not sure but try this setCartItems({...cartItems,[itemId]:1})

I can't see any obvious problems with the code you've presented here. (Not saying there aren't any, just that nothing obviously stands out as causing the problem you're having.) I suspect the problem is elsewhere - for example, you don't show how you're rendering the FoodItem components. If for any reason you were supplying the same id to each of those, that would likely cause the exact problem you're having.

Your code seems to correct and I am sure the source of the error you are having lies somewhere else.
First, make sure that each food item has a unique id.
And second, add some logs into the addtoCard function to check that the correct itemId is referred.
const addToCart = (itemId) => {
    console.log("Adding item to cart: ", itemId);
    if (!cartItems[itemId]) {
        setCartItems((prev) => {
            console.log("Previous state:", prev);
            return { ...prev, [itemId]: 1 };
        });
    } else {
        setCartItems((prev) => {
            console.log("Previous state:", prev);
            return { ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] + 1 };
        });
    }`enter code here`
};

And you could refine the function like this. it may help.
const addToCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => {
        const updatedCartItems = { ...prev };  // Clone the previous state
        updatedCartItems[itemId] = (updatedCartItems[itemId] || 0) + 1;
        return updatedCartItems;
    });
};

